# Iterating all columns with xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

Im having troubles getting all the row of a column. i have this

```
def excel(request):
    file_location = "proyectos.xls"
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        data = sheet.cell_value(0,col)
        return HttpResponse (data)
```

but this is returning the number of the all columns, does not return the values of the columns, how can i get all the values of a column excepting the header?

Comment: Currently that function isn't returning *anything*. Can you be more specific about what you want the function to do?

Comment: Sorry, i already edit the comment, it has to return the values of the column to 0 until "col"

Comment: With the code that you've presented, your `for` loop with only iterate once.

Comment: Ok, thanks.How can i iterate all the cols?

Comment: Values of the columns are provided by `col_values()`. Please see the [tutorial](http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf) (which is effectively the manual).

Comment: @JohnY Perhaps you mean `row_values()` as it the column value that is changing, not the row. That is, get the column values for a given row.

Comment: @Dunes: No, I mean `col_values()`. To me, the question "how can i get all the values of a column excepting the header?" sounds tailor-made for `col_values()`, with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: @JohnY rereading the text I think you are correct. My assessment was based on the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You could store all the cell values in a list, e.g.:

```
    ... 
    row = []
    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        row.append( sheet.cell_value(0,col) )
    return render_to_response('your_template.html', {'row': row})
```

And in your template something like:

```
{% for i in row %}
    <p>{{ i }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're most welcome. Cheers and happy coding to you.